# Why aren't my triggers firing during an insert by SSIS?

Tags: sql, triggers, ssis, bulkinsert

I have an SSIS data flow task with an OLE DB Destination component that inserts records into a table with a trigger.  When I execute a normal `INSERT` statement against this table, the trigger fires.  When I insert records through the SSIS task the trigger does not fire.

How can I get the trigger firing in SSIS?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Because the OLE DB Destination task uses a bulk insert, triggers are not fired by default.  From [BULK INSERT (MSDN)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx):

> If FIRE_TRIGGERS is not specified, no insert triggers execute.

One must manually specify **FIRE_TRIGGERS** as part of the OLE DB component through its Advanced Editor.

[image]

Then add "FIRE_TRIGGERS" to the value of *FastLoadOptions* (note that options are comma-separated):

[image]

With that option in place, the triggers should fire during the task's execution.

Comment: Does one have similar options if they are using and ADO.Net connection and working on an SQL database programmatically?

Comment: @NealR: yes, see [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Comment: I just want to add, with `OLE DB Destination`, if you have the `Keep nulls` checked, your triggers won't get fired either.

Comment: @JIsaak I had Keep Nulls checked and it did fire my trigger. I'm using SQL2008R2 and SSIS 2012

Answer (score 15):

complementing ladenedge's answer.

> Because the OLE DB Destination task uses a bulk insert, triggers are
>   not fired by default

that is true when you have the "fast load" option selected.

[image]

If you change it to a regular "table or view" data access mode, your triggers should fire normally because the insert is done  row-by-row

Comment: Typically you are using bulk load because your hundreds of thousands of rows are too slow to do a Row-by-Row operation on, many people will find this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using SQL Server Data Tool for Visual Studio by editing the dtsx File with Notepad (or any other Text editors).

Search for the following property:

```
<property
 dataType="System.String"
 description="Specifies options to be used with fast load.  Applies only 
 if  fast load is turned on."
 name="FastLoadOptions">
      TABLOCK,CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
</property>
```

and add the value FIRE_TRIGGERS as Diego already described.