# How to write SQL Trigger after inserting data from excel using import data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, triggers

I'm working with Sql server 2008 i have 2 tables,where table1 contains id,name,chk1,chk2,chk3 columns and table2 contains id,name,chk1,chk2,chk3 I want to load table2 with same data as table1 when i import data from excel to table1.Is is possible to use trigger on the event of import data using sql server 2008?

Comment: Trigger only for excel import or for all inserts ?

Answer (score 0):

Define an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on `table1`, the following will insert the data into `table2` after it has been inserted into `table1`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[table1AfterInsert] on [dbo].[table1]
AFTER INSERT AS

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table2 (id, name, chk1, chk2, chk3)
     SELECT id, name, chk1, chk2, chk3 from Inserted
END
```

Be aware that this will fire whenever records get inserted in `table1` regardless of the source of the insert.

As an addendum to my answer, using the basic import task wizard to import data from excel will not by default cause this trigger to fire.

You will need to save the package and edit the appropriate setting using BIDS, this answer has the details of that part [Getting triggers to fire via SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844219/why-arent-my-triggers-firing-during-an-insert-by-ssis)

Comment: @user2514925 see my updated answer, create my trigger first then check the link to the other answer about how to get the SSIS package to FIRE the trigger during import.

Comment: I'm using SQL server ImportData for data Porting Not using SSIS Package What will be the Trigger for this case?

Comment: @user2514925 Then a trigger won't work, you would just have to copy the data over using a standard T-SQL statement after you have run the import task.