# Trigger insert date failed when run job with SSIS packet

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a trigger to add date when insert record.

I worked fine when I inserted several records. However, it will not add date when I ran job with SSIS packet (over 20000 records).

I'm not sure why trigger will add date for small numbers of records but not for large numbers of records. Please can anyone help me fix this issue.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DateMod25] 
    ON [dbo].[ServiceArea]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE a
    SET [Modified] = GETDATE()
    FROM ServiceArea a
    INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON a.ServiceSite_ID = i.ServiceSite_ID
    WHERE a.Modified IS NULL;


END
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't my triggers firing during an insert by SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844219/why-arent-my-triggers-firing-during-an-insert-by-ssis)

Comment: So when you update a row in ServiceArea, you do NOT want to update the Modified column? That is the end-result of that WHERE clause. Your logic seems to be incorrect.

Comment: even if I remove WHERE clause and it wont make any change.