# SQL Server : trigger using After Insert, Update is not updating the hash column on insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm setting a hash on a table during insert and update to be used by another syncing process, and though it seems to work on update, it isn't working on insert.

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_SetSyncHash] 
ON [dbo].[person]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE p
    SET p.SyncHash = CAST(CHECKSUM(ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), p.AccountNumber), ''),
                                   ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), p.EMailAddress), ''),
                                   ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), p.Fax), ''),
                                   ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), p.Name), ''),
                                   ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), p.Telephone1), ''),
                                   ISNULL(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), p.Telephone2), '')) 
                          AS NVARCHAR(50))
FROM    
    [dbo].[person] p
INNER JOIN 
    Inserted i ON i.id = p.id;
GO
```

If the `Person` table is empty and I add 100 rows, the `SyncHash` column is not updated.

If I run something like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[person] 
SET SyncHash = '';
```

it will run the trigger and set the hash after the fact.

How can I get this to run correctly on insert as well?

I thought these ran after the commit so reading this data back in from the table would pick-up the inserted column values.

**Update**: I'm updating the table using a Data Flow in SSIS. It seems if I insert data into the table through T-SQL, the hash is updated from the trigger, but it's not when updating through SSIS. Not sure why this would matter, but for some reason it is. Thoughts from anyone?

Comment: Please do take the time to provide a proper [mre]. I, without one, cannot replicate your problem: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8BPnGVUs)

Comment: Maybe check if the SSIS flow disables the triggers on the table before executing?

Comment: Does [this question and answer help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10844219/1048425) - As an aside you may also want to consider a computed column (and persist if necessary), [example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8CKGycOs)

Answer (score 1):

If the OLE DB Destination component in the SSIS data flow is using the Fast Load mode it will not fire any Insert triggers unless the Fire_Triggers option is specified.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/ole-db-destination#fast-load-options